# os.startfile() opens wrong file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, chat

I am making a project for school. I have two scripts. One takes a target ip to send strings to, the other accepts data from that ip. One script opens the other script at a specific time in order to make it more user-friendly. However, instead of opening the right file, it opens the sending file, the file with the os.startfile(). Here are the scripts:

```
#!python3
import socket
import sys
import os

print ("MAGENTA Chat Host v1 - send")
target = input("Target IP:")
UDP_IP = target
os.startfile("ChatRcv.py")

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("Socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

while True:
    message = input ("Message:")
    if message == "exit":
        s.close()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        s.sendto(bytes(message, "utf-8"),(UDP_IP,5000))
```

Next

```
#!python3
import socket
import sys
from ChatSend import UDP_IP

print ("MAGENTA Chat Host v1 - receive")

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("Socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

s.bind((UDP_IP,5000))

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print ("Received message:", data)
```

What did I do wrong? Please help!
***EDIT-*** It's something to do with the import line, when I comment it out it works just fine. Getcwd() gives proper result. Using Python 3.5.2 and windows 32bit. Need help!

Comment: did you try giving absolute path?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. the ChatRcv file is in the same folder as this folder, and I've tried writing out the entire path. same result.

Comment: It would help if you identified the names of the the two scripts (not just blank and "Next").

Comment: The first one is ChatSend.py and the second one is ChatRcv.py

Comment: If you put the line `print(os.getcwd())` somewhere in the script, are the results what you expect them to be?

Comment: yes, they are correct with getcwd.

Answer (score 0):

`from ChatSend import UDP_IP` will run the entire script `ChatSend.py` (including starting another `ChatRcv` process), and after it finishes running, `UDP_IP` will become available to the `ChatRcv.py` program.

The following will give you control on what kind of code runs when you start the program directly vs when you import from it:

```
#!python3
# Code that will always run (e.g., during import)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code that will only run when you call the script directly.
else:
    # Code that will only run when you import.
```

If what you want is to pass the value of `UDP_IP` from `ChatSend.py` to `ChatRcv.py`, you can't do so by importing the variable, because you'll import it from a new instance of `ChatSend.py`, not from the original. Instead, you should pass it as an command-line argument to `ChatRcv.py`:

```
# ChatSend.py
...
import subprocess
UDP_IP = target
subprocess.Popen(["ChatRcv.py", UDP_IP])

# ChatRcv.py
# Instead of from ChatSend import UDP_IP
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    UDP_IP = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("You need to pass UDP_IP as an argument")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qscguest\Desktop\MAGENTA Chat\ChatSend.py", line 8, in <module>
    os.startfile("ChatRcv.py" + target)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'ChatRcv.py127.0.0.1'

Comment: I am using python 3.5.2, maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: On Windows. I edited my answer. If that doesn't work, try `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Python35\\python.exe", "ChatRcv.py", UDP_IP])`

Comment: The one you just commented gives me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qscguest\Desktop\MAGENTA Chat\ChatSend.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Python35\\python.exe", "ChatRcv.py", target])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The edit gives me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qscguest\Desktop\MAGENTA Chat\ChatSend.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["ChatRcv.py", target])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["python", "ChatRcv.py", UDP_IP]) or give the full path to the python.exe executable as the first element of the list.

Comment: It gave no error, finally! however, ChatRcv didn't stay open. It only flickered.

Comment: How do I get it to stay open?

Comment: Try: `subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "start", "c:/Users/qscguest/Desktop/MAGENTA Chat/ChatRcv.py", UDP_IP])`

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "start", os.getcwd() + "/ChatRcv.py", UDP_IP])